# UITabBarController.selectedIndex type dependant on architecture?

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

In my code I change the presented tab by assigning the proper value to `tabBarController.selectedIndex = TabBarIndex.tabA`

```
// Works when compiling for iPhone 5s
struct TabBarIndex {
    static let tabA = 0
    static let tabB = 1
    static let tabC = 2
    static let tabD = 3
}

// Works when compiling for an older device or when archiving the project
struct TabBarIndex {
    static let tabA = UInt(0)
    static let tabB = UInt(1)
    static let tabC = UInt(2)
    static let tabD = UInt(3)
}
```

Apple Documentation says `var selectedIndex: Int`. If I compile for an older device or want to archive the project in order to upload it to the App Store, I get the following compile error:

`Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'UInt'`

Only after replacing the *Int version* by the *UInt version* it works - and vice versa. It's the very only thing I have to manually change in order to compile for different devices locally (or archive) - is there a way not to?